# reset all original value of variable after end of quiz

Tags: jquery, math, while-loop, reset

I have set the var as following

```
var sum = 0;
var Correctscore = 0;
var Wrongscore = 0;
var QNum = 1;
```

I have a Addition Math quiz program. it has 10 questions. It generate 2 random numbers which is in the function call random(). user will put the answer in a text area, which is the "text" in the code.

The answer provided will be check with the sum of the 2 numbers. If it's correct, it display an window "you are correct", else "you are wrong"

```
random();

$(":button").click(function(){

if(QNum<10)
{
    if(text == sum)
    {
        alert("you are right");
        Correctscore = Correctscore + 1;

    }
    else
    {
        alert("you are wrong");
        Wrongscore = Wrongscore + 1;
    }
    QNum = QNum + 1;
    random();

   }
else
{
    alert("quiz end");
}

});
```

At the end of question 10, a window will display "quiz end". When user click ok, all the correct and wrong score will be reset to 0. Question number reset to 1.

I tried using while loop to check if QNum has reach 10 or not. But I keep getting a script error and I can't figure out why.

```
$(":button").click(function(){

while(QNum<=10)
{
 .....
}
alert("quiz end");

});
```

Another question is, after user press "OK" on the alert window "quiz end", how can I change all the score back to 0 and QNum back to 1?

What is the most efficient way to reset the quiz program?

Comment: what is the error you are getting? why don't you attach seperate click event handler for quiz end OK button and reset all flags

Comment: some little demo will be cool!

Answer (score 0):

Just put it inside `else`

```
if(QNum<10)
{

    ...

}
else
{

    sum = 0, Correctscore = 0, Wrongscore = 0, QNum = 1;
    alert("quiz end");

}
```

Comment: I change the if else to while loop. But using while loop, the program did not seems to be able to exit the loop to execute the next step which is the alert for quiz end. while if else works, I am thinking that it is very complicated as I will need to add a timer and even more conditions that need to be fullfilled later. I am trying to use the best practice for programming.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get this to work using while loop.

```
$(":button").click(function(){
while(QNum<=10)
 {
    if(text == sum)
    {
        alert("you are right");
        Correctscore = Correctscore + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("you are wrong");
        Wrongscore = Wrongscore + 1;
    }
    $("#question").html("Question " + QNum + "/10");
    QNum = QNum + 1;
    random();
    $(":text").val("");
    return false;
    }

 });
```

The variables remain unchanged.

```
var sum = 0;
var Correctscore = 0;
var Wrongscore = 0;
var QNum = 1;
```

I added in the *return false;* so that the while loop will work properly.

Without the *return false;*, the alert "you are wrong" keep popping up.

But there is a problem with this. The #Question display *Question 1/10* then follow by *Question 1/10* again before jumping to *Question 2/10* and finally ends at *Question 10/10*.

How can I solve this?

And base on this while loop, where can I place the following code?

```
sum = 0, Correctscore = 0, Wrongscore = 0, QNum = 1;
alert("quiz end");
```